How to share data between concurrently executed promises in NodeJS
I want to share data between the two concurrent method calls shown below.
async generateSuggestedSparks(userId: GraphID, friends: Person[], latLng: LatLng) {
    let suggestions = await this.generateAndMergeListsInParallel([
      this.generateHardCodedSparks(userId, friends, latLng),
      this.generateRandomActivitySparks(userId, friends, latLng, 6),
    ]);
    suggestions = this.filterDuplicateSuggestions(suggestions);

    return suggestions.slice(0, 7);
  }

  async generateAndMergeListsInParallel<T>(promises: Promise<T[]>[]): Promise<T[]> {
    let lists = await Promise.all(promises);
    return lists.flat();
  }

Each method generates a number of artifacts for a randomly selected subset of friends. In both methods, I remove selected friends from the friends list to avoid selecting the same friend multiple times. I would like to generalize this logic to share data across the two concurrent promises to avoid one choosing a friend already used in the other.
What is the canonical way to share data across the concurrently running methods in NodeJS?

I remove selected friends from the friends list to avoid selecting the same friend multiple times depending on how you are doing this, you may already be doing it right. We can't tell, because the functions that deal with friends are not visible to us

We have to see ALL the code that is operating on the shared data to know if you have a problem or not.  The answer is "it depends" upon what  you're doing and how to code is written.  Context switching can occur at an await or .then() so it depends upon what state that may be modified by other code that you hold onto across an await or .then().  For example if you hold an index position in an array across an await and that array may be modified by other code that can execute during that await, then you can create a problem for yourself.

There is a problem with premises presented in the question that may impede answering regardless of the expected nature of a solution: promises are passive objects, they are not executed, and hence they never "run". Promises either exist or have become eligible for memory garbage collection.
What promises are is a combination of

A wrapper around a single value of some data type in JavaScript along with the status of the data value as either 'pending', 'fulfilled' or 'rejected'.
An interface with the event loop similar to but more complex than a timer call such as setTimeout: promises don't use elapsed time to become settled and instead generalise asynchronous processing by using user calls to their resolve and reject functions to set the value and status of a promise's datum - or link it to the result of another promise if resolve is passed a promise-like object.

While many questions have been asked about "I don't understand why these promises became fulfilled in an order that I didn't expect", the reality is that such questions are theoretical: promises were designed to solve the problem that in general the time of completion of asynchronous operations is unpredictable.
The canonical answer to how to work around problems caused by by waiting for promise settlement in parallel is to no use Promise.all - wait for promise supply of data that impacts later promises in a chain by creating the promises in a chain.
Note that Promise handling of data base access results will not provide data base request optimization that may or may not be available by combining multiple RDMS queries into one.

JavaScript is a single-threaded language, it does not support or handle parallel requests natively. You will have to use some other framework to do the parallel processing. even with promises, the methods get executed one by one.

I'm aware that js is single threaded, hence "concurrent" and not "parallel".
My question is about sharing data between two different events in NodeJS. I expect the event loop to process the events in an interleaving fashion, as each has several await statements. I'm not familiar enough with the event loop to understand how this works. Will a pointer to an object suffice?

@ashissl what do you man by "a pointer to an object"? and "process the events in an interleaving fashion" - what events?

Why do you need a framework at all? How could a framework (written in JavaScript) solve a problem, that can't be solved with VanillaJs?
